# How to check passport number exist or not?

Tags: c#

I want to check passport number exist or not ,

before I used this code to check if integer number exist or not ,

but passport number column in MSSQL type varchar(50).

what I tried

1- created stored procedure to read ID No :

```
create proc [dbo].[VALIDATE_PATIENT_IDNO]

@patient_id varchar(50)
as 
select Patient_id from Patients
where Patient_id = @patient_id
```

2- I created this code in C# to validate id no exist or not :

```
public int? VALIDATE_PATIENT_IDNO(string patient_id)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlParameter[] Param = new SqlParameter[1];

            Param[0] = new SqlParameter("@patient_id", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
            Param[0].Value = patient_id;

            dt = DAL.SelectData("VALIDATE_PATIENT_IDNO", Param);
            DAL.close();

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
                int? patientNumber = row.Field<int>("patient_id");
                return patientNumber;
            }

            // return null otherwise
            return null;
        }
```

3- when type the id no or passport no when key down code :

```
private void textIDNO_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textIDNO.Text))
                {
                    txtpcfileno.Focus();
                }

                 else
                {
                    var patientNumber = patient.VALIDATE_PATIENT_IDNO(textIDNO.Text); // int?
                    bool patientExists = patientNumber.HasValue;

                    if (patientExists == true)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Id or Passport No Exist ", "ID EXIST", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtpcfileno.Focus();
                    }
                }   
            }
            
                  
        }
```

4- I have error appeared in the code in step 2 :

```
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
int? patientNumber = row.Field<int>("patient_id");
```

How to change the code in step 2 and solve this error and check string value not int?   ?

Comment: Try `row.Field<string>`, then convert it to `int`?

Comment: Don't store numbers in `varchar` fields. Store them in `int`

Comment: At least where I live, the passport "number" consists of letters (alphabetical) and digits. It may not be a good assumption that passport numbers can be treated as `int` values. With an int, you also throw away leading zeroes. Maybe all this explains why it is stored as a varchar.

Comment: @Charlieface I tend to agree but sometimes leading zeroes are important.

Comment: Agreed, but here why is OP converting to `int`, clearly it is an `int`? Admittedly, it **is** passport numbers so you're right.

Comment: thank you all yes passport number can be numbers and characters for this I used it as varchar datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting the naming confusions (passportnumber vs patientid) aside, you probably don't want to return the found patientids (because you already know them, as they are part of your selection condition) but the count.

Furthermore, your patientid seems to be a string, yet in your result you try to cast this to an integer. That is not possible, thus the error.

You can try as follows:

```
create proc [dbo].[VALIDATE_PATIENT_IDNO]

@patient_id varchar(50)
as 
select count(Patient_id) as patientcount from Patients
where Patient_id = @patient_id
```

Assuming that `patient_id` is the primary key of your table, this will either return `1` if a row with the given id exists or `0` if not.

Then you can do

```
int? patientNumber = row.Field<int>("patientcount");
```

and then

```
bool patientExists = patientNumber > 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much genius man and solution , if i can give you 1000 vote I will do ,  :) :) :)